# I've been despaired about "Failed to build gem native extension"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rubygems, installation, ubuntu-13.04

I installed rvm and ruby 2.0.0 on my ubuntu 13.04 and everything was fine, but the last step went wrong when I install rails 4.0.0
The following is what happened after I run: " gem install rails -v 4.0.0 ":

```
**Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    /home/adolph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile
make
compiling atomic_reference.c
linking shared-object atomic_reference.so
make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 atomic_reference.so /home/adolph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/atomic-1.1.14/lib/home/adolph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file ‘/home/adolph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/atomic-1.1.14/lib/home/adolph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux’: No such file or directory
make: *** [install-so] Error 1
Gem files will remain installed in /home/adolph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/adolph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out**

It looks like the *‘/home/adolph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/atomic-1.1.14/lib/home/adolph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-linux’* doesn't exist.
```

Please help me!

Comment: try with gem update --system 2.0.3

Answer (score -1):

You can try with this

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and after it

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Comment: Downvoted because Apt-packaged Ruby is hard to use, won't be the latest version, and the question needs a direct answer. Sry!